# Spring boot properties that depend on other properties

Tags: spring-boot

Do we have anyway where we can define one property is dependent on the other property?

**messages.properties**

```
product.name=XYZ
product.title=XYZ title
```

I have already tried the below one but its not working

```
product.name=XYZ
product.title=${product.name} title



@Bean
  public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource =
        new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
  }

@Component
public class Messages {

  @Autowired
  private MessageSource messageSource;

  private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
  }

  public String get(String code, @Nullable Object[] args) {
    return accessor.getMessage(code, args);
  }

  public String get(String code) {
    return accessor.getMessage(code);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What went wrong?

Comment: The value of product.title printed as `${product.name} title` not `XYZ title`

Comment: This works in Spring since version 2.5.3 :) according to the Spring changelog https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/changelog.txt

How do you retrieve the message!?

Comment: We have message component class as defined above and we are using messages.get("product.title") to get the value.